# Multiple business unit with API Integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

I'm trying to integrate with the Salesforce Marketing Cloud using API Integration from the App Center. Basically, we have multiple clients in our platform who wishes to push data into their ExactTarget account.

After reading through most of the documentations, I feel like this is not possible with API Integration since it's one app to a business unit. I was hoping to have our clients authenticate through our account, but the API looks like it doesn't return an ID etc.

What's an alternative? Would creating a package work better for this scenario instead?

Comment: You will need to create individual OAuth credentials for each Business Unit, however if you can let me know which API methods you intend to use, I may be able to advise an alternate solution.

Comment: @EliotHarper That was one of my options, but I was trying to figure out an automated way of doing so. Like authenticating with an email address and a password. The API in particular that I wanted to utilize was the content/asset api. I was hoping to push some images to be used for content builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is possible, but like Eliot states in hos comment, you just need to create credentials for each Client Account (or Business Unit) in the App Center and then have a set of credentials associated with each client in your platform.

Alternatively you can use an Import File Activity to add Data to the Data Extension. All you need is your data as a CSV file. You can automate this process through Automation Studio if you need data updated daily or even hourly.

For Enterprise accounts you can use Shared Data Extensions to get access to data on the Master Account on all Sub Accounts and thereby only need to put data into one Account.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I replied back to Eliot with the API in particular that I'm trying to use.

Comment: after some fiddling, this is what works for me as of the moment. Which is setting up the app center for each client and getting both the client_id and client_secret from them. This is because the access_token is the id to the salesforce marketing cloud of a client.

Comment: That is how we do it as well.